# Mouse click stuck and occasional keyboard freeze on Acer with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, freeze, acer

I recently installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 on an Acer laptop.

Many times a day the mouse click freezes. I can still move the cursor, but it is stuck on click and I cannot do anything with it other than move it around.
Occasionally the keyboard freezes as well, but the mouse is the main issue.

The only way to solve this is to restart the computer, but quite often the mouse click is stuck immediately after boot already, and I have to reboot multiple times for it to start working.

Note that I am only using the touchpad.

I tried changing the BIOS Touchpad settings to Basic, but that didn't help. Currently they are set back to Advanced.

When the mouse freezes and I press `Ctrl + Alt + F1`, and then log back in to the user, the mouse is fine again, so I guess this could be related to the Gnome desktop session?

Another clue is that while running Live Ubuntu from USB during install, the touchpad wasn't working at all.

Any clues appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could try to login by `ssh` from another machine (even a phone) and kill the user.  This may prove that the problem is in the user's session (usually the Gnome desktop).

Comment: I don't understand "cursor stuck on click".

Comment: It means I cannot click with the mouse. It seems that the cursor is stuck in such a way as if I was holding left click all the time.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE looks like you're right. I didn't do the SSH, but when the mouse froze again I did `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and then returned back to the user, and the mouse was repaired